How the size of a rule is connected with the box before/after it?
I am trying to understand how the height/width of a rule is determined in LaTeX. Here is the example below:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
% This \hrule is as long as the following box (string)
\hrule height 1pt As a philosopher, he was a leading representative of 17th-century rationalism and idealism.

\vspace{1cm}
% Why is this rule is as long as in the example above? Does LaTeX look backwards?
As a philosopher, he was a leading representative of 17th-century rationalism and idealism.\hrule height 1pt

\vspace{2cm}
% This \vrule has the height of the whole string/hbox (the maximum height of letters within the string)
\vrule width 1mm Two distinct things cannot have all their properties in common.

\vspace{1cm}
% Why these two \vrule's have the same height? After the first \vrule there is a word "common" that does not have "high" letters; the second \vrule has nothing after it at all but its height is the same.
Two distinct things cannot have all their properties in \vrule width 1mm common.\vrule width 1mm
\end{document}

I used to think that a rule has the same height/width as the next (following) box, so that a rule itself is sizeless but it takes the same size as the following box. But the example above shows that even if you put a rule after the box, the rule will have the same size as if it were before the box. Could you explain how LaTeX determines the size of a rule according to the box before or after the rule?

hrule and \vrule are tex primitives that  should not normally appear in a latex document, they have a synntax quite unlike latex taking height and width keywords rather than arguments.
That said, \hrule may only appear in vmode so if as in your second paragraph, it appears in hmode, TeX insert \par to end the paragraph then re-interprets the rule.
As the rules have no width specified they extend to the width of the current box, which is the text width here.
\vrule has to appear in hmode, so in your third example the paragraph starts and the vrule is in the first line of the paragraph. As you have not specified a height or depth all three of your vrules in the lasttwo paragraphs extend to the vertical height and depth of the hbox they are in, which is the hbox created by linebreaking, so for these paragraphs a box of height+depth \baselineskip

So am I right that a rule size depends on the box size where it is located? So when TeX is in vmode, all \hrule's and \hbox'es are in kind of one big \vbox and they must have the same common width equal to the width of their parent \vbox?

if you do not specify a key then the hrule extends to the wdith of itscontaining vbox and a vrule extends to the height and depth of its containing hbox @Vladimir

So when looking at the document I should keep in mind that its content is kind of in invisible boxes, one contains another. As I understood, the main (super) box is \vbox because initially TeX is in vmode. And this \vbox holds nested boxes and rules and, without specific parameters, all nested boxes have the common size of their parent box.

@Vladimir yes except last sentence not true, if you go \vbox{\hbox{aa}\hbox{bb}\hbox{ccc}} then the three boxes are all different widths, but if you have a vbox with a paragraph then that paragraph is broken in to lines all \hsize wide
